# Incluir archivo de script php clasico en Symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Tengo una clase `ApiController` y quiero incluir un archivo con la directiva `include_once` para incluir un archivo en `src/utilities.php` pero no me deja:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

    include_once 'src/utilities.php'; // Aquí no funciona

    class ApiController extends AbstractController
    {
        /**
        * @Route("/", name="home")
        */
        public function index()
        {
            return $this->json(
                [
                    'success'   => true,
                    'version'   => '1.0',
                    'message'   => 'Mi API'
                ]
            );
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asegúrate que ese archivo que intentas incluir exista, o que estés indicando la ruta correcta del archivo **utilities.php**

Prueba a poner el `include_once` así:

```
include_once ('src/utilities.php');
```

También puedes hacer un `var_dump()` para ver si te devuelve **TRUE** o **FALSE**

```
var_dump(include_once 'utilities.php');
```

Como última opción puedes utilizar `require_once()`:

```
require_once('src/utilities.php');
```

**Estructura:**

```
  src->
      utilities.php
  otraCarperta->
      archivoActual.php
```

Si tu estructura es parecida a la de arriba, para indicar la ruta a tu archivo **utilities.php** debería ser: `include_once ('../src/utilities.php');`

Comment: Probe de todas formas, pero no funciona. Me tira diferentes errores, uno de ellos me dice: "The file was found but the class was not in it, ...." asi supongo que Symfony4 no permite archivos php flat. Pero gracias por responder.

Comment: Ahora si, ahora entendí, tiene que ser una carpeta diferente de "src", puse "utilities.php" en una carpeta llamada "src-flat", fuera de "src". Ahora si funciona

Comment: @GermánMartínez Me alegro que haya funcionado.